# Problem with JSON_EXTRACT in two similar enviroments

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm using mysql 5.7 in two enviroments (staging and prod)
both with this same version
but when I try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `EVENT_ONDEMAND_MODULE_CONTENT` 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(EXTRA_INFO, '$.UPLOAD_ID') = 'Jh24ACh59sJ6mSSpQKXORJVscmy2iD3Dy1B0115L01hbI';
```

In staging that works, but in production I got this error:

SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Invalid escape character in string."

```
{"UPLOAD_ID":"Jh24ACh59sJ6mSSpQKXORJVscmy2iD3Dy1B0115L01hbI","POLICY":"signed","FILE_NAME":"VIDEO 10s.mp4","FILE_MIME_TYPE":"video\/mp4","READY":false}
```

I copy the json from prod to staging and the query worked too.

Anybody knows if have something I must do to this function Json_extract work in prod??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can we see the text with that invalid escape character ?

Comment: Ok, I Edit and put json and the key in query

Comment: There seems [no problem exists](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5d0d46fef5575f5f4d525e83a36f403a) .

Comment: It's probably related to the backslash in `"video\/mp4"`

Comment: Check what is escape character on the production server? Shown JSON literal is valid itself: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5108abbc047a272e0aa2eee175c67a70

Comment: How I identify the escape character in db ?